# Spivak's calculus, chapter 2 question 3 (c)

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing

The question is:
Give another proof that **$nCk$** is a natural number by showing that $nCk$ is the number of sets of exactly $k$ integers each chosen from $1,.....,2$.

I understand that I have to prove that $nCk$ is a natural number, but I do not understand the "set" part or what exactly the question asks of me. 
I can feel that the number will be a natural, but could anyone clarify both the question and the answer please? I am self-studying, thanks.

The answer from the solution manual is:
[image]

Comment: Typically when someone asks "how many" of something there are, the answer is a whole number. For instance, how many wheels are on a car; how many marbles are in a given bag, or... how many subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ have $k$ elements? Cars dont have $3.5$ wheels (hopefully), they have $4$. When you tally, or count, you end up with a whole number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ different letters and you want to make $k$-letter words, but you'll count all the $k!$ anagrams of the $k$-letter word as one word. How many different words are there? Well, you have $n$ choices for the first letter, $n-1$ for the second, ..., $n-k+1$ choices for the $k$th letter. So you have $(n)(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1) = \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ possible words. But we've agreed that the order of the $k$ letters doesn't matter, so we divide by $k!$ to account for the number of distinct possible words/anagrams. This is counting the number of $k$-element *subsets* of the set of $n$ letters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This clears all up.

Comment: You're most welcome. Welcome to MSE. You might want to wait to see if another answer is better for you, but try to get in the habit of accepting an answer once you're satisfied so that the question will go off the "unanswered" list. :)

Answer (score 0):

A set is a collection of objects, called elements. For example, $S = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ is a set containing 3 elements.

The approach is to select $k$ of $n$ integers, and determine how many unordered $k$-tuples can be formed.

Comment: Fixed the issue.